# «Нераскрываемое дело» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, причастия

Слитно или раздельно с **не** пишется слово **нераскрываемое** в словосочетании *нераскрываемое дело*? Противопоставления в предложении нет, поэтому я считаю, что слитно, но у другого человека возникли сомнения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из словаря современного жаргона российских политиков и журналистов (А. Моченов):
**висяк** (глухарь) — в СМИ термин заимствован из милицейского сленга. Обозначает бесперспективное, [нераскрываемое дело](http://rulibs.com/ru_zar/ref_dict/mochenov/0/j29.html) (как правило, убийство).

Раскрываемый — страдательное причастие (наст. вр. от *раскрывать*); нераскрываемый — причастие полное, пояснительных слов и противопоставления нет.
Вы правы — пишем слитно.

[Частица ***не*** с причастиями](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80)

"Нераскрываемые преступления" (книга); нераскрываемый шифр; *Странная элегия вполне может иметь какой-то нераскрываемый аллегорический смысл* (И. М. Гилилов).